# Loading file containing a matrix from octave

Tags: octave

I have a C++ program performing an iterative improvement procedure. I record the error in every step and I would like to import that data into octave to plot. My program writes the result as a matrix to a file named "err.m":

```
B = [
0 0.0566002;
1 0.0510102;
2 0.0510102;
3 0.0454972;
4 0.0418604;
5 0.0415802;
6 0.036775;
7 0.0298324;
8 0.0298324;
9 0.0298324;
]
```

(The actual file is of course much bigger.)
As soon as I fire up octave and enter

```
load 'err.m'
```

I get the error

```
error: load: err.m: inconsistent number of columns near line 2
error: load: unable to extract matrix size from file `err.m'
```

However, when I paste the contents of the file into octave directly, everything works fine (unless the matrix has to many rows). I googled the error but I found no solution to my problem, although the problem seems to be rather common.

Does anyone know how I can load the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

err.m:

```
0 0.0566002
1 0.0510102
2 0.0510102
3 0.0454972
4 0.0418604
5 0.0415802
6 0.036775
7 0.0298324
8 0.0298324
9 0.0298324
```

err1.m:

```
B = [
0 0.0566002;
1 0.0510102;
2 0.0510102;
3 0.0454972;
4 0.0418604;
5 0.0415802;
6 0.036775;
7 0.0298324;
8 0.0298324;
9 0.0298324;
];
```

In Octave:

```
octave:1> load 'err.m'
octave:2> err
err =

   0.00000   0.05660
   1.00000   0.05101
   2.00000   0.05101
   3.00000   0.04550
   4.00000   0.04186
   5.00000   0.04158
   6.00000   0.03678
   7.00000   0.02983
   8.00000   0.02983
   9.00000   0.02983

octave:3> err1
B =

   0.00000   0.05660
   1.00000   0.05101
   2.00000   0.05101
   3.00000   0.04550
   4.00000   0.04186
   5.00000   0.04158
   6.00000   0.03678
   7.00000   0.02983
   8.00000   0.02983
   9.00000   0.02983

octave:4> run 'err1.m'
B =

   0.00000   0.05660
   1.00000   0.05101
   2.00000   0.05101
   3.00000   0.04550
   4.00000   0.04186
   5.00000   0.04158
   6.00000   0.03678
   7.00000   0.02983
   8.00000   0.02983
   9.00000   0.02983

octave:5> B=load('err.m')
B =

   0.00000   0.05660
   1.00000   0.05101
   2.00000   0.05101
   3.00000   0.04550
   4.00000   0.04186
   5.00000   0.04158
   6.00000   0.03678
   7.00000   0.02983
   8.00000   0.02983
   9.00000   0.02983
```